# FPDF class extend not working

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm having a problem with FPDF because my class extend it's not working.

I'm creating a class for my footer and then call it with:

```
$pdf = new PDF2();
```

I have the code in a external file with an include above all the code, like this:

```
include"fpdf.php";

class PDF2 extends TFPDF
{
    // Page footer
    function Footer()
    {
        // MB LOGO 30cm before the end of the page
        $Y = $this->SetY(-65);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
        $this->SetFont('DejaVu','',10);
        //MB LOGO
        $this->Image('img/multibanco.jpg',20,$Y,30);
    }
}

//pdf begins
// Cliente info encomenda
$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf = new PDF2();
$pdf->addPage();

// Arial bold 15
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',11);

// Title
$pdf->Cell(190,10,'Ordem Nº '.$maxi.'',0,0,'C');

// Line break
$pdf->Ln(20);

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',10);

// Cliente nome/email
$pdf->Cell(150,10,'Cliente: '.$enc['nome'].' '.$enc['apelido'].' ',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(150,10,'Email: '.$enc['email'].'',0,1);
$pdf->setFillColor(232, 232, 232); 

//Messagem 
$pdf->RoundedRect(10, 50, 190, 10, 3.5,TRUE);
$pdf->Cell(190,10,'Mensagem',0,1,'L'); //header
$pdf->setFillColor(255, 255, 255); // background
$pdf->MultiCell(180,5,'Text',0,'J',0); // MENSAGEM

//TABELA
$html ='';
$html='<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="230" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Tipo</td>
        <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Formato</td>
        <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Nº Interno</td>
        <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Revelar</td>
        <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Digitalizar</td>
        <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Edição</td>
        <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Impressão</td>
    </tr>';

while($pdf_info2 = $smth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $html .= '
        <tr>
            <td width="230" height="40" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">'.$pdf_info2['Tipo'].'</td>
            <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">'.$pdf_info2['Formato'].'</td>
            <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">'.$pdf_info2['Revelar'].'</td>
            <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">'.$pdf_info2['Digitalizar'].'</td>
            <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">'.$pdf_info2['Edicao'].'</td>
            <td width="88" height="40" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">'.$pdf_info2['Impressao'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}

$pdf->WriteHTML($html);

//OUTPUT + LN
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->Output();
```

Any errors of the class are not displayed, at least I don't see them even without the error_reporting(0) commented.

Comment: enable error reporting by using `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I don't believe that "fpdf.php" contains a class definition for TFPDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not declare the object `$pdf` more than once, you must call the file tfpdf.php, there is built the class `tFPDF()`.

Example

```
<?php

// Optionally define the filesystem path to your system fonts
// otherwise tFPDF will use [path to tFPDF]/font/unifont/ directory
// define("_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", "C:/Windows/Fonts/");

require('tfpdf.php');

$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);

// Load a UTF-8 string from a file and print it
$txt = file_get_contents('HelloWorld.txt');
$pdf->Write(8,$txt);

// Select a standard font (uses windows-1252)
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->Write(5,'The file size of this PDF is only 12 KB.');

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Download the class tFPDF() in [http://www.fpdf.org](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)